# Add filetype "no extension"

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs, appx, appxmanifest

I am attempting to associate my WinJS-based app with extension-less files in my `package.appxmanifest` file. I have successfully associated `*.txt` files:

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
    <FileTypeAssociation Name="my-app-name">
      <SupportedFileTypes>
        <FileType>.txt</FileType>
      </SupportedFileTypes>
    </FileTypeAssociation>
  </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

but I can't find a way to associate files with no extension. I've tried adding

```
<FileType>.</FileType>
```

to no avail. What else can I do?